# I just installed Eclipse, can't seem to get it to work

Tags: eclipse, ide, helios

I'm very new to programming. But I started out with Eclipse after I couldn't seem to get `CodeBlocks` to function properly. Now when I installed it, and ran it for the first time (started an empty project and all), an error message was displayed

```
Building Workspace has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during the build.
```

I got curious and clicked on details, which showed

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Rand1'.
java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

I got a screenshot of the situation tagged to the post
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgJbT.png)

Comment: Eclipse helios is very old! You should really use the newer version (4.6 "Neon") which should work better and do more things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. run eclipse.exe with the -clean parameter. to do this either navigate to where you installed eclipse and go to properties on eclipse.exe and add -clean in the end of the parameter
2. run it via command. i recommend you to run via command so that it wont be a permenant thing whenever you start eclipse

Comment: Now it says "Launch failed. Binary not found.".

Comment: Have you tried building the project first?
at the top menu, press "Project > Build Project" and then try to debug your program. see if that works for you